# Which method to save dom should keep less memory?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

If we need to save a slice of dom elements in memory(we will insert it into dom tree dynamically later)
which method will keep less memory?

method 1:

```
var a = parentDom.innerHTML;
parentDom = null;
```

method2:

```
var a = parentDom;
```

Comment: Why do you care? Also, are you willing to trade off the time required to serialize/deserialize the DOM against some supposed memory savings?

Comment: This will probably depend a lot on the size of the DOM tree, the DOM's internal memory format, and how much additional data (like event handlers etc) is stored in the DOM that would be lost on serialisation. The best way to find out is to try both approaches, and measure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you have a massive structure I don't think the difference should be your concern. Also, as torazaburo mentioned, the cost of deserializing that string of innerHTML should be considered if you're worried about memory at this level.

What you should worry about, however, is any event listeners and such that would be lost if you only save the serialized string version. Also, you don't have the whole node, just its contents.